# Spyder 3 for Python running code

Tags: python, spyder

I've been trying to run some code in Spyder using their idle, but I keep getting an error such as SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Assuming that the file requires 2 inputs, for example, img1.bmp, and an integer (i.e. python file.py img1.bmp 4).

Answer (score 0):

The idle is a python interpreter, and it is giving you a python error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. You are already running python, so entering `python file.py img1.bmp 4` would not make any sense. You would need to run that in a command prompt. If you want to run it in a python interpreter, you could import your file and call the functions as needed.

Comment: I tried that, like file.py img1.bmp 4. But had no luck.

Comment: Can you be explicit about what you tried? You opened a command prompt, navigated to your directory with file.py, and ran python file.py img1.bmp 4?